# Changing div content on hover in another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

have been scratching my head over this for the past few days, basically the functionality I am going for is that I have a `<ul>` with 7 `<li>` elements and then I have another section with 7 `<p>` elements. What I am looking for is that when I hover on one of the `<li>` elements it puts the text from the corresponding `<p>` element. The thing is that I cannot play directly with the text or inject via jQuery, because the content in the `<p>` are references to yaml files. I have hidden all the elements except the first one which should appear on pageload, and then I guess there is a way of hiding the `<p>`'s and showing only the corresponding one. Thanks in advance! please find attached the code snippet:

```html
<section class="container clearfix">
  <div class="text-center">
    <ul class="solutions-items">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container clearfix">
  <div class="text-center solutions-text-p">
    <p class="">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <p class="hidden">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <p class="hidden">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <p class="hidden">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <p class="hidden">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <p class="hidden">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <p class="hidden">{% yaml reference %}</p>
    <button class="solutions-learnmore-btn">{% yaml reference %}</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not moving the text, but I guess just removes the class hidden, so that there is only one visible `<p>` at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to show the corresponding `p` when hovering an `li`, you can do it by index, or by associating them with a `data-*` attribute.

Here's an example by index:

- We hook `mouseenter` on the list, delegated so that we only receive the event when it relates to one of the `li`s
- When we get the event, we get the index of that `li` relative to its siblings
- Then we grab the paragraphs in the `solutions-text-p` `div`, make sure they all have the `hidden` class, then remove it from the one with the same index as the `li`

**Live Copy** - I've made the jQuery part fairly verbose for clarity:

```js
$(".solutions-items").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  var paras = $(".solutions-text-p p");
  paras.addClass("hidden");
  paras.eq(index).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container clearfix">
  <div class="text-center">
    <ul class="solutions-items">
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
      <li>Fifth</li>
      <li>Sixth</li>
      <li>Seventh</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container clearfix">
  <div class="text-center solutions-text-p">
    <p class="">First</p>
    <p class="hidden">Second</p>
    <p class="hidden">Third</p>
    <p class="hidden">Fourth</p>
    <p class="hidden">Fifth</p>
    <p class="hidden">Sixth</p>
    <p class="hidden">Seventh</p>
    <button class="solutions-learnmore-btn">{% yaml reference %}</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's a less verbose version of the jQuery:

```
$(".solutions-items").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
  $(".solutions-text-p p")
      .addClass("hidden")
      .eq($(this).index())
          .removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mouse enter event and index of the hovered element to show/hide the target elements

```js
var $ps = $('.solutions-text-p p')
$('.solutions-items li').mouseenter(function() {
  var $cur = $ps.eq($(this).index()).show();
  $ps.not($cur).hide();
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container clearfix">
  <div class="text-center">
    <ul class="solutions-items">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container clearfix">
  <div class="text-center solutions-text-p">
    <p class="">1</p>
    <p class="hidden">2</p>
    <p class="hidden">3</p>
    <p class="hidden">4</p>
    <p class="hidden">5</p>
    <p class="hidden">6</p>
    <p class="hidden">7</p>
    <button class="solutions-learnmore-btn">{% yaml reference %}</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `The thing is that I cannot play directly with the text or inject via jQuery, because the content in the <p> are references to yaml files.` - I am not sure what does the OP mean by this but I think he is not looking for jquery solution. I may be wrong though..

Comment: @Mr_Green: I think it means he can't have the content in the code; Arun's solution (and mine), though, just shows/hides the content where it's already been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.solutions-items li').mouseenter(function() {
    $("#show_data").text($(this).data("text"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="container clearfix">
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="solutions-items">
            <li data-text="bla_1">1</li>
            <li data-text="bla_2">2</li>
            <li data-text="bla_3">3</li>
            <li data-text="bla_4">4</li>
            <li data-text="bla_5">5</li>
            <li data-text="bla_6">6</li>
            <li data-text="bla_7">7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container clearfix">
    <div class="text-center solutions-text-p">
        <p id="show_data"></p>
        <button class="solutions-learnmore-btn">{% yaml reference %}</button>
    </div>
</section>
```